# Shared Voltmeter for 2 DC Circuits at Different Voltages (battery & solar)

Tags: voltage, dc, solar-cell

I want to use one panel mount voltmeter (Powerwerx PanelDVM) for measuring both my 12VDC Battery output and the input voltage from a Solar panel ,which has a higher DC Voltage. This all is hooked to a battery charge controller (shown below). I will be using a SPDT switch (on-off-on) to switch between voltages and would hook both the solar and battery grounds together at the switch, but I am not sure if this would cause a issue. Such as: damage to the solar panel. It may be better to buy 2 voltmeters

[image]
**update:** I agree with everyone that said: "Use a DPDT Switch".  I only went this route because I had a hard time finding a round, center off, Panel mount, DPDT switch, but it really isn't worth risking damage to the Solar panel.

Comment: Why risk damaging hundreds of dollars of equipment to save fewer than ten?

Comment: Why not use a DPDT switch?

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't know how the solar panel is wired into the charge controller, I'd suggest that you simply use a DPDT switch.  This allows you to move the voltmeter between the two sources without any interaction.

You could also use a DPDT Center-Off switch, which allows you to disconnect the voltmeter completely if you wish.

Note that the solar panel voltage may be significantly higher than that of the battery, especially during a very bright sunny day with your battery fully charged.

Comment: The funny thing was I originally ordered a specific DPDT switch (round one with center off) online from DelCity and they were out of stock(and still are out of stock) so I bought a SPDT for a few bucks. I will have to find the DPDT somewhere else. Thanks Dwayne